# Selecionar uma opção no input radio a partir da data de nascimento preenchida

Tags: html, css, javascript-eventos

Eu tenho o seguinte codigo

eu gostaria de selecionar se ele é maior de idade automaticamente a partir da data de nascimento preenchida no input type date`

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="born_date">Data de Nascimento</label>
  <input type="date" name="born_date" id="born_date" class="form-control" value="" required>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
 <label for="" aria-required="true">Participante é maior de 18 anos?</label>
  <div class="mt-2">
   <label for="legalage">SIM
    <input type="radio" name="legalage" id="yes" class="square-radio" value="yes">
   </label>
    <label for="no">NÃO
     <input type="radio" name="legalage" id="no" class="square-radio" value="no">
    </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Faltou colocar seu javascript.

Comment: como eu nao entendo muito de javascript eu nao coloquei

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fazendo umas pesquisas achei o melhor jeito de resolver esse problema

segue o codigo

```js
function calculateAge(birthDate) {
  var today = new Date();
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var monthDiff = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (monthDiff < 0 || (monthDiff === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}

//marca a opção sim ou não dependendo dos dados que voce informa na data de nascimento e  desabilita o radio para não marcar outra opção
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#born_date").change(function() {
    var birthDate = new Date($("#born_date").val());
    var age = calculateAge(birthDate);
    if (age >= 18) {
      $("#yes").prop("checked", true);
      $("#no").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#no").prop("checked", true);
      $("#yes").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
                            
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="born_date">Data de Nascimento</label>
  <input type="date" name="born_date" id="born_date" class="form-control" value="" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="" aria-required="true">Participante é maior de 18 anos?</label>
  <div class="mt-2">
   <label for="legalage">SIM
    <input type="radio" name="legalage" id="yes" class="square-radio" value="yes">
   </label>
    <label for="no">NÃO
     <input type="radio" name="legalage" id="no" class="square-radio" value="no">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).